# How to change the text on a Back Button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, back-button, uinavigationitem

I've created a Navigation Controller, with a bar button item. This button leads me to another view, and perfectly creates a back button. I just want to change the text of this button, so I typed it in Navigation Item > Attributes Inspector > Back Button, but it doesn't work and I've the following warning :

> Title set but using a system Identifier (These attributes are mutually
>   exclusive; the Title will be ignored)

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the Back button is easy, here are ways to change to either text or an image, you will want to place these in your **`viewDidLoad`** method.

### `UIImage`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_home.png"]];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

### `NSString`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[backButton setTitle:@"Go Back!"];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```